# When should technical details be considered while reviewing?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension, late-answers

Recently I have been suspended from reviewing because of this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26703316.

While I understand now that the answer is actually wrong due to technical concerns (the answer doesn't solve the problem), I thought only the format was important (i.e. spam, very low quality, etc.).

Should technical details always be considered? In other words, if I don't understand the post technically, I shouldn't review it?

Comment: For Late Answers and First Posts, familiarity with the technology involved is many times required. Otherwise it's not possible to judge if post is actually any good and what kind of vote it deserves. If you do not know enough to form a judgement, just press _skip_.

Comment: Even pedople with familiarity i has difficulties to see that that answer is wrong, it looks ok to me too, so it is impossible to guess

Comment: @yivi I would stress that familiarity (and some other extra things) is required only when going to pick "Looks OK". One doesn't need any familiarity with technical matters nor even looking at the question at all to review an "answer" like "I have same problem, have you resolved?"